# Multiple GoPros on one computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-camera, gopro, gopro-wifi

I am planning on using 2-3 GoPros streaming to one computer for something I’m working on, and I know I can use Wi-Fi to stream over a network. Problem is, GoPros are access points, not clients, so I can't do that easily. I was gonna get a few Wi-Fi adapters to use, but then I realized that the IP is static and they will all have the same one, so I can't do that either. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Looking online there appear to be several methods of doing this. Have you found and tried any of these yet?

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Yup, thanks! I got the accounts merged now. @music2myear the only thing I could find was using periscope on Hero 4 and up, but even thats only a single camera. I also saw how to use a single wifi remote on multiple cameras, which isnt what I want either. I want each camera streaming to my pc, even with some delay is fine